# Is there a Heap in java?

Tags: java, heap

I am porting a C++ library to Java and I need a heap data structure. Is there a standard implementation or will I need to do it myself?

Comment: In addition to the native `PriorityQueue`, guava provides a [`MinMaxPriorityQueue`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098277/java-implementation-for-min-max-heap

Answer (score 167):

For Java 8, updating on an existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54665261/319876):

You can use Java Priority Queue as a Heap.

**Min Heap:** --> to keep the min element always on top, so you can access it in O(1).

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

**Max Heap:** --> to keep the max element always on top, the same order as above.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Which is the same as `(Integer o1, Integer o2) -> Integer.compare(o2, o1)` or `- Integer.compare(o1, o2)` as suggested from other answers.

And you can use:
`add` --> to add element to the queue. O(log n)
`remove` --> to get and remove the min/max. O(log n)
`peek` --> to get, but not remove the min/max. O(1)

Comment: Isn't remove supposed to be o(1) in heaps? Those are the performance of RBT

Comment: Hi @IlyaGazman you will need to do heapify after every add or remove, so you can keep the balance of the heap, that is why those 2 operations are in O(logn). You can also check this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-and-deletion-in-heaps/

Answer (score 53):

Min heap:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

Max heap:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return - Integer.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
```

Comment: `- Integer.compare(o1, o2);` shall be same as  `Integer.compare(o2, o1);`

Answer (score 33):

In Java [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) can be used as a Heap.

**Min Heap**

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

**Max Heap**

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: how is it different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54665261/1746118) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833871/1746118) answer?

Comment: At the time I wrote it, no other answer showed the option of `Comparator.reverseOrder()`. Some answered posted and some edited after my post

Answer (score 11):

PriorityQueue uses a heap.  Based on the oracle documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html it seems likely that it is an implementation of a binary heap.  I don't think there is an  official implementation of a fibonacci or pairing heap, though I'd love to see either one of the two available.

Answer (score 1):

No as such there isn't but you can use Priority Queue as a Heap. Its officially told by Oracle to use Priority Queue as a Heap you can also refer to [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for further clarification.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> MinHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();

PriorityQueue<Integer> MaxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: how is it different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54665261/1746118) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833871/1746118) answer?

Answer (score 1):

From Java docs `PriorityQueue` which is available since 1.5 is the class to use.

This code for `Min Heap` *creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)* in which the min is at the top.

```
//MIN HEAP
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>();
//equivalent to 
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(11);
```

If you want to implement a special ordering you need to override the comparator with this constructor

```
PriorityQueue​(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator);
```

Since 1.8 we also have this version

```
PriorityQueue​(Comparator<? super E> comparator);
```

which helps you create the `Max Heap` in more elegant ways such as

```
//MAX HEAP
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = 
new PriorityQueue<>((n1,n2) -> Integer.compare(n2,n1));
//equivalent to 
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

For a special case check this example that shows the natural ordering for a custom object, in a scenario where we order customers based on their distance to a fictional restaurant

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class DeliveryHandler {

    private static final Address restaurant = new Address(5.0, 5.0);

    private static class Address implements Comparable<Address> {
        public double x, y;

        public Address(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double distanceToShop() {
            return Math.pow(restaurant.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(restaurant.y - y, 2);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Address other) {
            return Double.compare(this.distanceToShop(), other.distanceToShop());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Address {x=%s, y=%s}".formatted(x, y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Address> customers = List.of(
                new Address(13, 14),
                new Address(3, 1),
                new Address(9, 20),
                new Address(12, 4),
                new Address(4, 4));

        PriorityQueue<Address> queueServingClosest = new PriorityQueue<>();
        queueServingClosest.addAll(customers);
        while (!queueServingClosest.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(queueServingClosest.remove());
        }

        /* Prints
        Address {x=4.0, y=4.0}
        Address {x=3.0, y=1.0}
        Address {x=12.0, y=4.0}
        Address {x=13.0, y=14.0}
        Address {x=9.0, y=20.0}
         */

        PriorityQueue<Address> queueServingFurthest = new PriorityQueue<>(
                (a1, a2) -> Double.compare(a2.distanceToShop(), a1.distanceToShop())
        );
        queueServingFurthest.addAll(customers);
        while (!queueServingFurthest.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(queueServingFurthest.remove());
        }

        /* Prints
        Address {x=9.0, y=20.0}
        Address {x=13.0, y=14.0}
        Address {x=12.0, y=4.0}
        Address {x=3.0, y=1.0}
        Address {x=4.0, y=4.0}
         */
    }
}
```

Refs

1- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

2- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: How is this any different than the already provided answers ?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev it gives more refs, tells when the  class was introduced and updated, gives an example to natural ordering and other uses for a custom object not only Integers. thanks for asking

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which guarantees log(n) time for basic operations (add, remove, contains).

Comment: TreeSet provides different characteristics then a heap. Priority Queue is the Heap structure in java.util.*

Comment: Actually, TreeSet uses a TreeMap internally, which it is a Red-Black Tree implementation so it is different than a heap.