# Most efficient way to get top k items in an array list Java

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, memory-efficient

I am trying to find the fastest and most efficient way to get the first top K items in arrayList of objects based on a custom compareable implementation.

during my research some suggested that i should use Max/Min heap which is abstracted in java as PriorityQueue. However, the problem is I dont know how to implement that on an arrayList of objects

here is my Object instance

```
public class PropertyRecord {

    private long id;
    private String address, firstName, lastName, email, ownerAddress;
    private LocalDate dateSold;
    private BigDecimal price;


    public PropertyRecord(long id, String address, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String ownerAddress, LocalDate dateSold, BigDecimal price) {

        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.ownerAddress = ownerAddress;
        this.dateSold = dateSold;
        this.price = price;

    }
 //getters and setters...
}
```

i want to get the first top k items based on the price. I have written a method (see below) which takes the arrayList and K (get first K items) and used StreamAPI but i know it is not the most efficient way to do it because this will sort the whole list even though I want only the first K items. so instead of having an O(n) i want have O(k log n).

```
//return the top n properties based on sale price.
    public List<PropertyRecord> getTopProperties(List<PropertyRecord> properties, int n){

       //using StreamAPI
       return properties.stream()
               .sorted((p1, p2) -> p2.getPrice().compareTo(p1.getPrice()))
               .limit(n)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

Any Help Please?

Comment: Can you just sort the list? and take top k or bottom k?

Comment: I can sort it but i don't want to sort the whole list. if i have 1000 items why sort the whole list even though i want the first top 10 lets say?

Comment: Sorting a subset of the list doesn't make any sense, as you don't know the maximum value, where it's located, etc.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: Replace your `List` with an implementation of a heap like you were suggested.

Comment: how? that is my problem how can implement that? any code example?

Comment: A quick Google search yields the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165325/is-there-a-heap-in-java

Comment: It's not possible to have any algorithm faster than O(n) becasue every element must be inspected at least once.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How turn an ArrayList into a PriorityQueue? Why do you need the ArrayList so badly that you cannot just stick to using a PriorityQueue?

Comment: Also, consider whether or not this List<PropertyRecord> is going to be read or written to more frequently.  If you use a PriorityQueue, your reads for the top K should be constant, but your writes will be O(log(n)).  However, if you use a typical List implementation, your writes (assuming you only add to the tail) will be constant, but your reads for top K will be O(n).  Choose wisely.  Profile your application to determine how much CPU time is spent where, or if it's even a performance issue at all.

Comment: my program has a lot of things to do with ArrayList such as search the ArrayList and get an item based on the ID, also get total amount of property prices in a specific date. So changing my data structure from ArrayList to PriorityQueue would ruin other functionalities! don't you think so ? or PriorityQueue would give me all of that more efficiently. it just i have never used PriorityQueue and that is why I am sticking with ArrayList not to mention that performance does matter in my program a lot.

Comment: I looked up for TreeMap and it seems suitable for my case except that I cannot sort it by value and only can sort it by keys. So i cannot have TreeMap<Long, PropertyRecord> sorted by PropertyRecord.getPrice(). any idea how to overcome this issue ? i want to keep the keys as long for fast retrieval and PropertyRecord as values!

Answer (score 2):

Guava contains a [TopKSelector](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/TopKSelector.java) class that can do exactly this.

In the latest Guava version, this functionality is now exposed as [`Comparators.greatest()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#greatest-int-java.util.Comparator-).

However, if you're not locked into using an `ArrayList` for storage, you're probably better off using a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) which will naturally keep the elements in priority order.

Comment: well, my program has a lot of things to do with array list such as search the arraylist and get an item based on the ID, also get total amount of property prices in a specific date. So changing my data structure from ArrayList to PriorityQueue would ruin other functionalities! don't you think so ?

Comment: You're probably better off building a custom data storage object that exposes the operations you need, which underneath the hood could be implemented with multiple data structures. For your purposes, a heap (PriorityQueue) and hashtable (HashMap) combination sounds like a good choice.

Comment: HashMap would be used for what in my case? searching?

Comment: Yes, lookup by (non-contiguous) ID is pretty much the canonical use case for a hashtable.

Comment: After doing some research i ended up with LinkedHashMap data structure which will allow me to read my csv (each row represent a propertyRecord in the csv file) and while reading i will add these records to the LinkedHashMap sorted based on their price and each has the ID as their keys. So when I search for a record (property) i will look for its key only and no need for iteration. and at the same time i can get top k records fast and easy based on their prices since they are already sorted from the beginning. What do you think ?

Comment: If you don't need to worry about data changing over time, then sorting the data once is the fastest possible solution. The purpose of things like `PriorityQueue` is to allow you to insert and remove records efficiently while still allowing you to iterate them in priority order. In your case, `LinkedHashMap` is probably good enough, but you might also consider using a `TreeMap` which will sort using your comparator; there are trade-offs either way. If your data never changes then I would sort it once and then keep it in a Guava `ImmutableMap`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168670/discussion-between-faisal-julaidan-and-daniel-pryden).

Comment: I looked up for TreeMap and it seems suitable for my case except that I cannot sort it by value and only can sort it by keys. So i cannot have TreeMap<Long, PropertyRecord> sorted by PropertyRecord.getPrice(). any idea how to overcome this issue ? i want to keep the keys as long for fast retrieval and PropertyRecord as values!