# How to find the max element in a deque in java in O(1) amortized time?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, deque

In java, I'm implementing a deque using LinkedList. `Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<>()`.

My deque has the following methods:
`addFirst(Integer x)`
`addLast(Integer x)`
`Integer removeFirst()`
`Integer removeLast()` and
`Integer max()`

The `max()` method needs to find the max element in the deque in O(1) amortized time and return it.

Currently I am using `Deque<Integer> max_deque = new LinkedList<>()` to store the max element of the deque but I am having trouble updating the max element in this data structure when the add and remove operations are performed on `deque`.

How do I go about implementing this so that the max element gets updated and returned in O(1) amortized time? Thank you!

Comment: By definition, you cannot go through the whole list in O(1). If you need that, you must make sure to check and update the max value every time you add or remove from your `Deque`. For removing, that most likely means an O(N) check if you removed the current max element.

Comment: Consider using a Heap which returns max in O(1): `PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());` 
- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165325/is-there-a-heap-in-java . Of course, adding elements is not O(1)

Comment: So you need the `max()` function to have `O(1)` complexity. But the other functions don't have to be `O(1)`, right?