# How to write multi cookies from server side to browser?

Tags: http, setcookie

I'm using [vert.x](http://vertx.io/) to write an application. It doesn't have built-in cookie support yet, and we have to use "putHeader()" method to manually set cookies.

Now I want to set several cookies, so I write:

```
 req.response.putHeader("Set-Cookie", "aaa=111; path=/")
 req.response.putHeader("Set-Cookie", "bbb=222; path=/")
 req.response.putHeader("Set-Cookie", "ccc=333; path=/")
```

But I found vert.x send only one "Set-Cookie":

```
 Set-Cookie ccc=333; path=/
```

I'm not sure if I misunderstand something. Can server send multi "Set-Cookie" commands one time? Is it correct to send multi cookies this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no, it's impossible out of the box because headers stored in a HashMap:
https://github.com/purplefox/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vertx/java/core/http/impl/DefaultHttpServerResponse.java#L81

You can:

- Open new issue
- Comment existing issue https://github.com/purplefox/vert.x/issues/89
- Checkout source and use map what allow duplicate keys
  [Map implementation with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys) (you need handle duplicate manually, for instance Location-header should be only one time
- Extend DefaultHttpServerResponse and see how you can integrate it
- Merge cookies and handle it manually, for instance:

  req.response.putHeader("Set-Cookie", "aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=333; path=/")

Answer (score 2):

Use netty's `io.netty.handler.codec.http.ServerCookieEncoder` functionality:

```java
req.response.putHeader("Set-Cookie", 
        ServerCookieEncoder.encode(new DefaultCookie("aaa", "111")))
```

there're many useful method signatures:

```java
ServerCookieEncoder.encode(Cookie cookie)
ServerCookieEncoder.encode(Cookie... cookies)
ServerCookieEncoder.encode(Collection<Cookie> cookies)
ServerCookieEncoder.encode(Iterable<Cookie> cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one work-arround.

```
req.response()
.putHeader("Set-Cookie", "some=cookie;max-age=1000;path=/;HttpOnly"
    +"\nSet-Cookie: next=cookie"
    +"\nSet-Cookie: nnext=cookie;HttpOnly");
```