# How to store non-unique key value pair in core java 1.4

Tags: java, data-structures

i need to store non unique key value pair like in an application which can only be compiled with java 1.4. It should look like :

```
{"key1"=>"value1",
"key2"=>"value2",
"key3"=>"value3",
"key3"=>"value4"
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>` not good enough? Also, Java 1.4? What the …?! It’s now ten years old, and outdated for 8 years. That’s way beyond a software’s best-before date.

Comment: i know it sucks to use java 1.4 ... but it's a legacy app which is still breathing

Comment: Well, can’t the legacy app be compiled under newer Java versions? And if it can’t – how much effort would it be to bring its codebase up to date? After all, Java is almost completely backwards compatible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are application servers out there that run on Java 1.4. There really is no help.

Answer (score 1):

In core java, I think you are stuck with storing arrays or lists as the values of a Map interface (hashmap). You might also consider answers here: [Map implementation with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys)

What are the semantics of asking for a duplicate key?