# How can i have a HashMap in Java with duplicate keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a collection in Java that is going to store a pair, a key and a value.

So I decided to use a `HashMap<String,String>`, but I noticed that when I try to add a key that already exists, the previous (key,value) is replaced by the new one (NewKey,NewValue) and the previous entry is lost. So when I have duplicate keys, the previous key is replaced by the new one.

How can I have a HashMap with duplicate keys?

Comment: What would you expect to get back when you retrieved by a key?

Comment: that's called a list of key/value pairs, not a map

Comment: Can i List store a pair of a key and a value?

Comment: the question is, what you doing that you need that behavior? you may use a Map<String,List<String>>

Comment: I need to store a pair of a key and a value, but i would like to have duplicate keys

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys

Comment: ok i'll check that post thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `MultiMap`, 
take a look at [Google Guava Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: the link above is broken.

Comment: i've updated link

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map a key to a collection of values, take a look at Guava's [`Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). If you don't want to use a third-party library, you can simulate a `Multimap` with a `Map<String, Collection<String>>`. The [Java tutorial on the `Map` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) has an example of implementing a `Multimap`.