# Map with duplicate values

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have gone through questions relate to the same questions, but I am not getting a clear idea of how to implement the map with duplicate entries. I was asked this question in my interview. Please give me some guidelines.

For instance, a company has two employees of same name and same area of development viz.
`map.put("Tom Hank","Java");`

`map.put("Tom Hank","Java");`

As we all know, we cannot store duplicate values in `HashMap`. So can I implement this and retrieve the values according to key? Or any other better solution?

These are the questions that I have gone through but not able to understand how to do this.

[How to include duplicate keys in HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18922165/3035579) |
[How can i have a HashMap in Java with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18968479/2041986)

Comment: What didn't you understand from those questions? The answers there even included working example.

Comment: The answers were related to Google's libraries, but my interviewer might be interested in the logic.

Comment: Why not use a Map<Key, List<Value>>?

Comment: Did your interviewer really told you to use a map? I  mean, I' would definitely create an `Employee` class, have a `Set<String>` as an attribute in it, storing area of development, and then maintain a `Set<Employee>`.

Comment: "I am not getting a clear idea of how to implement the map with duplicate entries" - `Map`s don't have duplicate keys, end of story. Either your interviewer was playing a joke on you, or you haven't given us the whole question.

Comment: You _can_ have the same _values_ just not the same _keys_

Comment: @RohitJain Thank you mate, but can you elaborate it more, so that I can answer the same question (if asked) next time.

Comment: @peeskillet He was saying that I need to put two same keys in a map.

Comment: Great idea. But How do you tell which Tom Hank is the right one?

Comment: @Vito Adding some identification to it like `unique ID` or some `EmployeeId`

Comment: @Prasad That's the trick. In my view using non-unique IDs in similar scenarios can lead to problems. Databases/SQLs operate on unique keys so things are well defined and without ambiguity. I think this is probably worth mention answering questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map does not supports duplicate keys. you can use collection as value against same key.

Because if the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

you can use something like this.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will help you:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiHashMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap;

public class TryingMultiMap {
    public Map<String, String> testMap(MultiMap m) {
        Map<String, String> m_copy = new HashMap();
        m_copy.putAll(m);
        System.out.println(m_copy);
        return m_copy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
        MultiMap m = new MultiHashMap();
        m.put("Bhaskar","Java");
        m.put("Bhaskar","Java");
        m.put("Ravi",".Net");
        m.put("Ravi", ".Net");
        m.put("Suyash","C++");
        System.out.println(m);

        /*Map exhibitMap= new HashMap();
        h.put("Bhaskar", "Java");
        h.put("Bhaskar", "Java");
        System.out.println("exhibitMap"+ExhibitMap)*/;

        TryingMultiMap obj = new TryingMultiMap();
        obj.testMap(m);
    }

}
```

How it brings in your problem into picture, is by having a multimap which can contain duplicates. Finally, multimap is put in the map and you find the MultiMap with duplicates added in the new Map too. Also, find the commented code in the main method, which exhibits the fact that Map cannot hold duplicates.

However, I find the solution provided by Armas is also a very appropriate one. 
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Type [multimaps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) in Google, and you will find what you are looking for.

Another way of doing it would be doing a simulated multimap the following way:

```
Map<String, List<String>> multimap=new Map<String, List<String>>();
if (multimap.contains("Tom Hanks"){
   multimap.get("Tom Hanks").add("value2");
}
else {
   List<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
   values.add("value1");
   multimap.put("Tom Hanks", values);
}
```

But finding a multimaps implementation will save you all the trouble.

Comment: Note that I am not doing any safety checks (for null values) in this code. The code is just a way to illustrate how to fake a multimap.

Comment: Google's Multimap is the way to go