# Java or guava map implementation to use with multiple keys pointing to single value

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I have a situation where many many keys are pointing to a single value. The situation arises from a service locator pattern that I am implementing such that -

- each method in an interface is represented as a signature string
- All such signatures of a single interface are used as keys
- The value being the full canonical name of the implementation class

Thus my need is to retrieve a single value when user requests any of the matching keys.

In a sense I need an opposite of MultiMap from Guava .

I am looking for the most optimized solution there is since my keys are very similar though unique for a specific value and I am not sure if using a generic Map implementation like HashMap is efficient enough to handle this case.

e.g. all the below signatures

==============

_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_testOperationThree
_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_getService
_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_start
_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_testOperationTwo_String_int
_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_getName
_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_shutdown
_org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestService_testOperationOne_String

=======

Point to a single class i.e. org.appops.server.core.service.mocks.MockTestServiceImpl and I am anticipating hundreds of such classes (values) and thousands of such similar signatures (keys) .

In case there is no optimized way I could always use a HashMap with replicated values for each group of keys which I would like to avoid.

Ideally I would like to use a ready utility from Guava.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys but is different since I have a single value (not a collection) for multiple unique keys

Comment: To be precise I am looking for the most efficient data structure to manage this. I am aware a HashMap can be used with duplicate values. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashMap` is actually what you need, and the issue is that you misunderstand what it does.

> In case there is no optimized way I could always use a HashMap with replicated values for each group of keys which I would like to avoid.

`HashMap` does not store a copy of the value for each key mapping to that value.  `HashMap` stores a *reference* to the Java object.  It's always the same cost.  A `HashMap<Integer, BigExpensiveObject>` where every key is mapped to the same `BigExpensiveObject` takes *exactly the same* amount of memory as a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` where every key is mapped to the same `Integer`.  The only memory difference in the whole program would be the memory difference between *one* `BigExpensiveObject` and *one* `Integer`.

Comment: Oops.. agreed.. didn't think about throughly I guess.