# What is difference between null and empty list?

Tags: java

```
List<Map<String, Object>> pcList = null;
Map<String, Object> pcMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ComputerConfigurations tempPC = null;

if (historyList != null) {
    Iterator<ComputerConfigurations> iterator = historyList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        tempPC = (ComputerConfigurations) iterator.next();
        pcMap.put(tempPC.getEnvironment(), tempPC);
        pcList.add((Map<String, Object>) pcMap);
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception on `pcList.add((Map<String, Object>)pcMap);` line. `[Servlet Error]-: java.lang.NullPointerException` . Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, collections won't magically spring into existence just by adding something to them.  You have to initialize `pcList` by creating an *empty* collection first:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> pcList = new ArrayList<>();
```

An empty collection isn't the same as `null`.  An empty collection is actually a collection, but there aren't any elements in it yet.  `null` means no collection exists at all.

Note that an object can't be of type `List`, because that's an interface; therefore, you have to tell Java what kind of `List` you really want (such as an `ArrayList`, as I've shown above, or a `LinkedList`, or some other class that implements `List`).

Comment: Thanks @ajb. Good clarification of null and empty. I need to revise question. Just one question..hashmap does not allows duplicate keys; any suggestion for that ? I am trying to achieve map of (Key - AMD, Value - all motherboard types) that can eventually be List<Map<string, object>>

Comment: See [Map implementation with duplicate keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising `pcList` at any point.  Try this:

```
    final List<Map<String, Object>> pcList = new LinkedList<>();
    Map<String, Object> pcMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ComputerConfigurations tempPC = null;

    if (historyList != null) {
        Iterator<ComputerConfigurations> iterator = historyList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            tempPC = (ComputerConfigurations) iterator.next();
            pcMap.put(tempPC.getEnvironment(), tempPC);
            pcList.add((Map<String, Object>) pcMap);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based answer. In this example below pcList is just initialized and is pointed to null(java do this for you, if it's a static or class member) since there are no empty list or values assigned to it.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> pcList;
```

---

Right now, pcList is assigned a new empty ArrayList. It does not have any values yet, but all positions in the list are empty and this pcList with the datatype ArrayList is pointed towards this new empty ArrayList.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> pcList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If an Object reference has been declared but not instantiated, its value is null.

Comment: How does this add any more useful information to the answers already provided a couple years ago?

Answer (score -1):

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> pcList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> pcMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ComputerConfigurations tempPC = null;

    if (historyList != null) {
        Iterator<ComputerConfigurations> iterator = historyList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            tempPC = (ComputerConfigurations) iterator.next();
            pcMap.put(tempPC.getEnvironment(), tempPC);
            pcList.add((Map<String, Object>) pcMap);
        }
    }
```