# java.lang.NullPointerException error in java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a garage in java. I have got a NullPointerException when I call the method addOption on my object Lagouna in my Main "Test". It is strange because it works when I call my method setMoteur. My object Lagouna is not null. My object GPS is not null as well.

**Main**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Garage garage = new Garage();   
     System.out.println(garage);

     Vehicule lag1 = new Lagouna();
     lag1.setMoteur(new MoteurEssence("150 Chevaux", 10256d));
     lag1.addOption(new GPS()); // here is my error

    }
}
```

**Class Vehicule**

```
public abstract class Vehicule {

protected double prix;
protected String nom;
protected Marque nomMarque;
protected List<Option> options;
protected Moteur moteur;


Vehicule(double prix,String nom,Marque nomMarque){
    this.prix=prix;
    this.nom=nom;
    this.nomMarque=nomMarque;
}
Vehicule(){
    prix=0d;
    nom="";
    nomMarque=null;
    options=null;
    moteur=null;
}
public String toString() {
    String str="Je suis une voiture "+ nom + " de la marque "+ nomMarque;
    return str;
    }

public void addOption(Option opt) {
    options.add(opt);
        }
public Marque getMarque() {
    return nomMarque;
    }
public List<Option> getOptions() {
    return options;
    }
public double getPrix() {
    return prix;
    }
public void setMoteur(Moteur mot) {
    this.moteur=mot;
    }
}
```

**Class Lagouna**

```
public class Lagouna extends Vehicule {

    Lagouna(){
        super();
    }
}
```

**Class GPS**

```
public class GPS implements Option{

static double prix=113.5d;
    public double getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }
}
```

**Class Option**

```
public interface Option {

public double getPrix();
}
```

Comment: `addOption` calls `options.add(opt);`; and what value do you assign to `options`?

Comment: The default value of options is null(see the constructor)

Comment: Yes. And what happens if you invoke an instance method on a null reference?

Comment: NullPointerException? But how can I initialize myList<Option>?

Comment: Initialize it to the value you want. For exapmle, `options = new ArrayList<>();` if you want it to be initially empty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305512/what-is-difference-between-null-and-empty-list

Comment: It works. Thanks.