# Remove key if value is empty

Tags: java, java-8

Say we have a `Map<Key, Collection<Value>> myMap` and a method that removes a value from the collection associated to a key. If removing a value leaves the collection empty, we'd want to get rid of the `key` entry in the map:

```
List<Value> removeValue(Key key, Value value) {
    List<Value> v = myMap.get(key);
    if (v != null) {
        v.remove(value);
        if (v.isEmpty())
            myMap.remove(key);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Is there any Java 8 way to achieve the described behavior with a one-liner or shorter method?

Comment: Nothing better comes to mind immediately.  This might be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: Your original method seems wrong, but it doesn't seem to be too verbose anyway...

Comment: `if (v.size() == 1) myMap.remove(key);` looks wrong. What if the list does not contain the value?

Comment: You may benefit from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1062960/5743988) to learn about the MulitMap in some libraries (not a duplicate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) for this:

```
static <K, V> List<V> removeValue(K key, V value, Map<K, List<V>> map){
    return map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, l) -> l.remove(value) && l.isEmpty() ? null : l);
}
```

`computeIfPresent` applies the `BiFunction` to the key and the current value in the map if the value is not `null` (if it is `null` `computeIfPresent` returns `null` immediately) and then either sets the value to the return value of the `BiFunction` if the return value is not `null` or removes the key from the map if the return value is `null` and finally returns the new value.

Note that it behaves slightly differently to the method in you question -  it will not remove an already empty `List` from the map because `remove` will return `false`. If you want to remove an already empty `List` you could use `l.isEmpty() || (l.remove(value) && l.isEmpty())`.

Comment: Thank you! Weird that I understand better the second form (which is what I was looking for precisely) than the first. Also, could something similar be done for putting elements? I can't think how because I see that both `computeIfPresent` and `computeIfAbsent` should be used. Or can it be one-lined as well?

Comment: @dabadaba if you want to create the list if it is not present then add to it you could use `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(v)`

Comment: @dabadaba For that you should just use [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) so that its okay for it to be `null`. Like `myMap.compute(key, (k, l) -> { if (l == null) l = new ArrayList<>(); l.add(value); return l; });`

Comment: By the way I just tested your solution and `||` removes all elements from the list and wipes it. It should be `&&` instead.

Comment: So the trick is that when `l.isEmpty()` then `null` is returned and `computeIfPresent` clears the mapping to `key`? That's the whole **it** to removing the key right?

Comment: @dabadaba Yes, and I made a mistake with the `||` part.