# Select every row with exact map key and value

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Here is a part of my Person class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<String, String> externalPropertyMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

So i need to select every Person with exact key and value from this map. For example select every Person with `key="prefferedNumber"` and `value="123456"`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not accurated:

> So i need to select every Person with exact key and value from this map

You have a `HashMap`, a `Map` implementation which don't allow repeated keys, so, **you just will get one single value for each key from the `HashMap`**.

To achieve this you need to use another `Map` implementation, but don't worry, someone has your problem already:

- Try [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6352551/3850595)
- [`MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) from ApacheCommons

  > A `MultiMap` is a Map with slightly different semantics. Putting a value into the `Map` will add the value to a `Collection` at that key. **Getting a value will return a `Collection`, holding all the values put to that key.**

Comment: But every Person is individual class, so every map is individual too and keys will not repeat at each person