# List of map to cucumber steo

Tags: java, cucumber-java

I have the following step:
User creats something using the following input:

```
|Key|value|
|Key|value|
```

Meaning duplicate values are being passed to step. So I thought I should use `list<Map<String,String>>` in the step definition but it is being passed as `(key=key, value=value)`

Could you please help me on how should I reserve this issue?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to do something like this?
<key1,value1>, <key2,value1>, <key3, value2>

Comment: Yes, but key-value pair may be duplicate and I want cucumber to pass every entry to step definition. When i make the data table as List<Map<String,String>> then the data table is being stored as (key=key, value=value) not as (key=value, key=value), could you please help me here how should I store it?

Comment: Is this your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062960/map-implementation-with-duplicate-keys

Comment: I can do whatever written in the link above, but the problem is cucumber only converts the data table to Map<k,v>, list<Map<k,v> where k and v should be Integer, String , Boolean or Float.

Comment: you can try [gerkin using qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html). Refer different [examples](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/test/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/impl/step/qaf/QAFTestStepImpl.java#L82) of step implementation and [exampe usage](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/test/resources/features/gherkin_datatable.feature)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming following feature file

```
Feature: demo for a key,value data table
  Scenario: duplicate data for a scenario
    When some condition is true
    Then enter a valid data pair
        |Key    |value|
        |Key    |value|
        |SomeKey|SomeValue|
```

and you want to execute the scenario for all listed rows, regardless the duplicated row `Key,value`.

The step can be implemented using a [DataTable](https://static.javadoc.io/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/2.4.0/index.html?cucumber/api/DataTable.html) parameter

```
public void enterAValidDataPair(DataTable dataTable) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("dataTable.raw().size() = " + dataTable.raw().size());
    for (List<String> row : dataTable.raw()) {
        System.out.printf("key: %-10s value: %-10s%n", row.get(0), row.get(1));
    }
}
```

if you run the scenario the method produces following output

```
dataTable.raw().size() = 3
key: Key        value: value     
key: Key        value: value     
key: SomeKey    value: SomeValue
```